# Safehandle in C#

Tags: c#, .net

What is SafeHandle? how does it differ from IntPtr? When should I use one? What are its advantages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) is pretty clear in definition:

> The SafeHandle class provides critical
>   finalization of handle resources,
>   preventing handles from being
>   reclaimed prematurely by garbage
>   collection and from being recycled by
>   Windows to reference unintended
>   unmanaged objects. Before the .NET
>   Framework version 2.0, all operating
>   system handles could only be
>   encapsulated in the IntPtr managed
>   wrapper object.
>
> The SafeHandle class contains a
>   finalizer that ensures that the handle
>   is closed and is guaranteed to run,
>   even during unexpected AppDomain
>   unloads when a host may not trust the
>   consistency of the state of the
>   AppDomain.
>
> For more information about the
>   benefits of using a SafeHandle, see
>   Safe Handles and Critical
>   Finalization.
>
> This class is abstract because you
>   cannot create a generic handle. To
>   implement SafeHandle, you must create
>   a derived class. To create SafeHandle
>   derived classes, you must know how to
>   create and free an operating system
>   handle. This process is different for
>   different handle types because some
>   use CloseHandle, while others use more
>   specific methods such as
>   UnmapViewOfFile or FindClose. For this
>   reason, you must create a derived
>   class of SafeHandle for each operating
>   system handle type; such as
>   MySafeRegistryHandle,
>   MySafeFileHandle, and
>   MySpecialSafeFileHandle. Some of these
>   derived classes are prewritten and
>   provided for you in the
>   Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles namespace.

Answer (score 14):

You should use a derivative of SafeHandle whenever possible where managed code is receiving an IntPtr from unmanaged code. While the name, general use, and even documentation of the SafeHandle class implies that it is only supposed to be used to contain Windows operating system handles, a few internal .NET framework classes such as Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeLocalAllocHandle and those that derive from the publicly available abstract class [System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.safebuffer(v=vs.100).aspx) also use it to guarantee that other unmanaged resources such as dynamically allocated structs and arrays are freed. In general, I believe that it is good practice to create a derivative of this class whenever an IntPtr is returned to managed code from unmanaged code even if it doesn't require cleanup.

The established purpose of a SafeHandle is to guarantee that even if the world is ending (e.g. an AppDomain is being unloaded or a StackOverflowException occurs) the .NET framework should make absolutely sure that the finalizer for the SafeHandle is called to close or deallocate the unmanaged entity being referred to by the wrapped IntPtr. The SafeHandle class achieves this by inheriting from the [CriticalFinalizerObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject(v=vs.100).aspx) class. Inheriting from this class does, however, place upon the inheritor the obligation of not totally screwing up the state of the process when the finalizer is called, which is likely why it is not often used for entities other than Windows operating system handles. The .NET framework also provides some weak finalization ordering so that it is safe to interact with a SafeHandle object in the finalizer of any class that does not inherit from CriticalFinalizerObject, but circumstances in which that is necessary should be few and far between.

Ideally, a SafeHandle-derived class should also be used to more safely interact with an unmanaged entity reference by encapsulating expected functionality within the derived class. A well-written class that inherits from SafeHandle should have a specific purpose in mind and should provide methods that are sufficient to prevent any developer using it for that purpose from ever needing to interact directly with the IntPtr it contains. Adding such methods also provides other developers with a clear idea of what the result of an unmanaged method call is to be used for in a managed context. A class that inherits from SafeHandle can be used for this even if no cleanup is required on the pointer that the unmanaged method returns by calling base(false) in the constructor for the class.

Two examples that use classes which derive from SafeHandle to safely clean up a reference to an unmanaged entity and encapsulate functionality related to the unmanaged entity are below. The first example is a more traditional scenario in which a user token returned by [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) is wrapped by an instance of the SafeTokenHandle class. This class will call CloseHandle on the token when the object is disposed or finalized. It also includes a method called GetWindowsIdentity that returns a WindowsIdentity object for the user represented by the user token. The second example uses Windows built-in function [CommandLineToArgvW](http://www.bing.com/search?q=CommandLineToArgvW&form=DLCDF8&pc=MDDC&src=IE-SearchBox) to parse a command line. This function returns a pointer to an array contained a contiguous block of memory that can be freed by a single call to LocalFree. The SafeLocalAllocWStrArray class (which inherits from class SafeLocalAllocArray which is also defined in this example) will call LocalFree on the array when object is disposed or finalized. It also includes a function that will copy the contents of the unmanaged array to a managed array.

```
static class Examples
{
    static void Example1_SafeUserToken()
    {
        const string user = "SomeLocalUser";
        const string domain = null;
        const string password = "ExamplePassword";
        NativeMethods.SafeTokenHandle userToken;
        WindowsIdentity identity;

        NativeMethods.LogonUser(user, domain, password, NativeMethods.LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, NativeMethods.LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out userToken);

        using (userToken)
        {
            // get a WindowsIdentity object for the user
            // WindowsIdentity will duplicate the token, so it is safe to free the original token after this is called
            identity = userToken.GetWindowsIdentity();
        }

        // impersonate the user
        using (identity)
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = identity.Impersonate())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm running as {0}!", Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        }
    }

    static void Example2_SafeLocalAllocWStrArray()
    {
        const string commandLine = "/example /command";
        int argc;
        string[] args;

        using (NativeMethods.SafeLocalAllocWStrArray argv = NativeMethods.CommandLineToArgvW(commandLine, out argc))
        {
            // CommandLineToArgvW returns NULL on failure; since SafeLocalAllocWStrArray inherits from
            // SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid, it will see this value as invalid
            // if that happens, throw an exception containing the last Win32 error that occurred
            if (argv.IsInvalid)
            {
                int lastError = Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "An error occurred when calling CommandLineToArgvW.");
            }

            // the one unsafe aspect of this is that the developer calling this function must be trusted to
            // pass in an array of length argc or specify the length of the copy as the value of argc
            // if the developer does not do this, the array may end up containing some garbage or an
            // AccessViolationException could be thrown
            args = new string[argc];
            argv.CopyTo(args);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Argument {0}: {1}", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// P/Invoke methods and helper classes used by this example.
/// </summary>
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    // documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, LogonType dwLogonType, LogonProvider dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    // documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    // documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern SafeLocalAllocWStrArray CommandLineToArgvW(string lpCmdLine, out int pNumArgs);

    // documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366730(v=vs.85).aspx
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hLocal);

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps a handle to a user token.
    /// </summary>
    public class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new SafeTokenHandle. This constructor should only be called by P/Invoke.
        /// </summary>
        private SafeTokenHandle()
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new SafeTokenHandle to wrap the specified user token.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arrayPointer">The user token to wrap.</param>
        /// <param name="ownHandle"><c>true</c> to close the token when this object is disposed or finalized,
        /// <c>false</c> otherwise.</param>
        public SafeTokenHandle(IntPtr handle, bool ownHandle)
            : base(ownHandle)
        {
            this.SetHandle(handle);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides a <see cref="WindowsIdentity" /> object created from this user token. Depending
        /// on the type of token, this can be used to impersonate the user. The WindowsIdentity
        /// class will duplicate the token, so it is safe to use the WindowsIdentity object created by
        /// this method after disposing this object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>a <see cref="WindowsIdentity" /> for the user that this token represents.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">This object does not contain a valid handle.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">This object has been disposed and its token has
        /// been released.</exception>
        public WindowsIdentity GetWindowsIdentity()
        {
            if (this.IsClosed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("The user token has been released.");
            }
            if (this.IsInvalid)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The user token is invalid.");
            }

            return new WindowsIdentity(this.handle);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls <see cref="NativeMethods.CloseHandle" /> to release this user token.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the function succeeds, <c>false otherwise</c>. To get extended
        /// error information, call <see cref="Marshal.GetLastWin32Error"/>.</returns>
        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return NativeMethods.CloseHandle(this.handle);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A wrapper around a pointer to an array of Unicode strings (LPWSTR*) using a contiguous block of
    /// memory that can be freed by a single call to LocalFree.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class SafeLocalAllocWStrArray : SafeLocalAllocArray<string>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new SafeLocalAllocWStrArray. This constructor should only be called by P/Invoke.
        /// </summary>
        private SafeLocalAllocWStrArray()
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new SafeLocalallocWStrArray to wrap the specified array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The pointer to the unmanaged array to wrap.</param>
        /// <param name="ownHandle"><c>true</c> to release the array when this object
        /// is disposed or finalized, <c>false</c> otherwise.</param>
        public SafeLocalAllocWStrArray(IntPtr handle, bool ownHandle)
            : base(ownHandle)
        {
            this.SetHandle(handle);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Unicode string referred to by an unmanaged pointer in the wrapped array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">The index of the value to retrieve.</param>
        /// <returns>the value at the position specified by <paramref name="index" /> as a string.</returns>
        protected override string GetArrayValue(int index)
        {
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(this.handle + IntPtr.Size * index));
        }
    }

    // This class is similar to the built-in SafeBuffer class. Major differences are:
    // 1. This class is less safe because it does not implicitly know the length of the array it wraps.
    // 2. The array is read-only.
    // 3. The type parameter is not limited to value types.
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps a pointer to an unmanaged array of objects that can be freed by calling LocalFree.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the objects in the array.</typeparam>
    public abstract class SafeLocalAllocArray<T> : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new SafeLocalArray which specifies that the array should be freed when this
        /// object is disposed or finalized.
        /// <param name="ownsHandle"><c>true</c> to reliably release the handle during the finalization phase;
        /// <c>false</c> to prevent reliable release (not recommended).</param>
        /// </summary>
        protected SafeLocalAllocArray(bool ownsHandle)
            : base(ownsHandle)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the unmanaged object referred to by <paramref name="valuePointer" /> to a managed object
        /// of type T.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">The index of the value to retrieve.</param>
        /// <returns>the value at the position specified by <paramref name="index" /> as a managed object of
        /// type T.</returns>
        protected abstract T GetArrayValue(int index);

        // 
        /// <summary>
        /// Frees the wrapped array by calling LocalFree.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the call to LocalFree succeeds, <c>false</c> if the call fails.</returns>
        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return (NativeMethods.LocalFree(this.handle) == IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copies the unmanaged array to the specified managed array.
        /// 
        /// It is important that the length of <paramref name="array"/> be less than or equal to the length of
        /// the unmanaged array wrapped by this object. If it is not, at best garbage will be read and at worst
        /// an exception of type <see cref="AccessViolationException" /> will be thrown.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="array">The managed array to copy the unmanaged values to.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">The unmanaged array wrapped by this object has been
        /// freed.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">The pointer to the unmanaged array wrapped by this object
        /// is invalid.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="array"/> is null.</exception>
        public void CopyTo(T[] array)
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
            }

            this.CopyTo(array, 0, array.Length);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Copies the unmanaged array to the specified managed array.
        /// 
        /// It is important that <paramref name="length" /> be less than or equal to the length of
        /// the array wrapped by this object. If it is not, at best garbage will be read and at worst
        /// an exception of type <see cref="AccessViolationException" /> will be thrown.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="array">The managed array to copy the unmanaged values to.</param>
        /// <param name="index">The index to start at when copying to <paramref name="array" />.</param>
        /// <param name="length">The number of items to copy to <paramref name="array" /></param>
        /// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">The unmanaged array wrapped by this object has been
        /// freed.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">The pointer to the unmanaged array wrapped by this object
        /// is invalid.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="array"/> is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is less than zero.-or- 
        /// <paramref name="index" /> is greater than the length of <paramref name="array"/>.-or-
        /// <paramref name="length"/> is less than zero.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">The sum of <paramref name="index" /> and <paramref name="length" />
        /// is greater than the length of <paramref name="array" />.</exception>
        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index, int length)
        {
            if (this.IsClosed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());
            }
            if (this.IsInvalid)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This object's buffer is invalid.");
            }
            if (array == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
            }
            if (index < 0 || array.Length < index)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", "index must be a nonnegative integer that is less than array's length.");
            }
            if (length < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", "length must be a nonnegative integer.");
            }
            if (array.Length < index + length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("length", "length is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of array.");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            {
                array[index + i] = this.GetArrayValue(i);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The type of logon operation to perform.
    /// </summary>
    internal enum LogonType : uint
    {
        LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 1,
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 4,
        LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 5,
        LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 6,
        LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The logon provider to use.
    /// </summary>
    internal enum LogonProvider : uint
    {
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 1,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Another way of looking at it: with SafeHandle, you should *almost* never need to write another finalizer.

Comment: I see. Though we need to write a method to free that handle overriding ReleaseHandle(). Which I think is called during the finalization process.

Comment: Yes, when you need to create your own type of handle. If you're creating code which uses an existing kind of handle, however, you're fine.