# Is it advisable to use a SafeHandle when calling an object's method also destroys the object?

Tags: c#, rust, pinvoke, ffi

There is a Rust library that provides three functions:

- a constructor for a vector of floats
- a function to push a number to the vector
- a function that sums over the vector

Like this:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn initialize_vector() -> *mut Vec<f32> {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(Vec::<f32>::new()))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn push_to_vector(ptr: *mut Vec<f32>, x: f32) -> *mut Vec<f32> {
    if ptr.is_null() { return ptr; }
    let vector_box = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) };
    let mut example_vector = *vector_box;
    example_vector.push(x);
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(example_vector))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn sum_vector(ptr: *mut Vec<f32>) -> f32 {
    if ptr.is_null() { return 0.0; }
    let vector_box = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) };
    let example_vector = *vector_box;
    return example_vector.iter().sum();
}
```

`initialize_vector` creates a `Vec` and wraps it in a `Box`, returning the raw pointer to the caller. The caller is now responsible for appropriately freeing the allocation.

`push_to_vector` takes ownership of the `Box<Vec<f32>>`, [moves the `Vec` out of the `Box`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42264041/155423), freeing the memory allocated by `Box` in the process. It then adds an item to the vector, creates a brand new `Box` (with associated allocation) around the `Vec` and returns it.

`sum_vector` also takes ownership of the `Box<Vec<f32>>`, moves the `Vec` out of the `Box` and frees the memory allocation. Since ownership of the `Vec` doesn't leave the function, Rust will automatically free the memory associated with the `Vec` when the function exits.

The C# code that uses the library could look like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Blabla
{
    [DllImport("Example")]
    unsafe static public extern IntPtr initialize_vector();

    [DllImport("Example")]
    unsafe static public extern IntPtr push_to_vector(IntPtr ptr, float x);

    [DllImport("Example")]
    unsafe static public extern float sum_vector(IntPtr ptr);

    static public unsafe void Main()
    {
        IntPtr vec_ptr = initialize_vector();
        vec_ptr = push_to_vector(vec_ptr, (float) 2.2);
        vec_ptr = push_to_vector(vec_ptr, (float) 3.3);
        float result = sum_vector(vec_ptr);
        // is the memory allocated for the vector in Rust freed right now?
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result: {0}", result));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In general, it is recommended to use `SafeHandle` to finalize pointers returned by DLL functions, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155780/safehandle-in-c-sharp) or [this example](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/). I understand that the purpose of `SafeHandle` is mostly to call a destructor in certain cases, when something unplanned happens.

Since it is not necessary to free the Rust vector after the `sum_vector` function has been called, is it still advisable to use `SafeHandle` in the given situation, and if yes - how? Or can I just leave the code as it is and everything is fine?

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but I'd say the code example provided doesn't make sense. There's no *reason* to take ownership of the `Box<Vec<f32>>` in either `push_to_vector` or `sum_vector`. If you simply changed these functions to *borrow* the data and restored the destructor, the code would be more performant (less unneeded (de-)allocation) and simpler. Is this just an artifact of creating a MCVE?

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the hint! The example is pretty similar to what I actually do, except that it is not floats but structs and that the analog of `sum_vector` does some heavy calculation. Thus, performance of allocation / deallocation is not important. But I could still apply the changes that you suggest (i.e., only borrow the vector and finally use a destructor) in order to manage the pointer in C# with the `SafeHandle` class.

Comment: @Shepmaster And how can I even push to the vector without taking ownership?

Comment: `Vec::push` only takes a `&mut Self` and `iter` only needs a `&Self`. You [can dereference and re-reference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6048282d021a31ca61f5e43157ee1366&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Comment: *performance of allocation / deallocation is not important* — I would disagree, but only benchmarking can say for sure. My gut says that de-allocating and re-allocating memory for *every item you push* is extremely wasteful.